# List of objects with a large size but all null values

Tags: java, serialization, null

I am iterating through a list of Strings (paths) and using File("path") to open these files (mp3). I then get the metadata and set the values of that metadata in an object (Song) . I am then adding that song to a list and pass that to be written to a serialized file.

My problem is that when I populate my Song list to send to be written, in debug it has a size of 49K objects and all are null.  But each object has the values which I set.  If I try to size I get a null pointer exception.

Here is the relevant code:

Song Class (Pretty standard...Only concern is the implementation of Serializable):

```
package com.bkane56.mp3;


import java.io.Serializable;

public class Song implements Serializable {

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String path;
    private String songName;
    private String artistName;
    private String albumName;
    private String releaseDate;
    private String trackNumber;
    private String composer;
    private String genre;
    private String length;
    private String publisher;
    private int artistID;
    private int albumID;

    public Song(){
    }

    public Song(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public Song(String path, String songName, String artistName,
                String albumName, String releaseDate, String trackNumber,
                String composer, String genre, String length, String publisher,
                int artistID, int albumID) {
        this.path = path;
        this.songName = songName;
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.albumName = albumName;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
        this.composer = composer;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.length = length;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.artistID = artistID;
        this.albumID = albumID;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getAlbumName() {
        return albumName;
    }

    public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
        this.albumName = albumName;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getTrackNumber() {
        return trackNumber;
    }

    public void setTrackNumber(String trackNumber) {
        String[] tNumber = trackNumber.split("/");
        if (tNumber.length > 1) {
            this.trackNumber = tNumber[0];
        }else {
            this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
        }
    }

    public String getComposer() {
        return composer;
    }

    public void setComposer(String composer) {
        this.composer = composer;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public int getArtistID() {
        return artistID;
    }

    public void setArtistID(int artistID) {
        this.artistID = artistID;
    }

    public int getAlbumID() {
        return albumID;
    }

    public void setAlbumID(int albumID) {
        this.albumID = albumID;
    }

    public String getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(Long microseconds) {
        int mili = (int) (microseconds / 1000);
        int sec = (mili / 1000) % 60;
        int min = (mili / 1000) / 60;
        length = String.format("%d:%02d", min, sec);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Values for this song:");
        sb.append("\n\tArtist: " + artistName);
        sb.append("\n\tTitle: " + songName);
        sb.append("\n\tRelease Date: " + releaseDate);
        sb.append("\n\tTrack Number: " + trackNumber);
        sb.append("\n\tComposer: " + composer);
        sb.append("\n\tPublisher: " + publisher);
        sb.append("\n\tLength: " + length);
        sb.append("\n");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Call to populate the song and songlist and pass the list to be written:

```
public static void savePopulatedList(){
        List<Song> myList = populateFromFile();
        SerialUtilities utilities = new SerialUtilities();
        utilities.saveSerializedSongInfoFile(myList);
    }
```

Here is the method for getting the metadata and setting the values in the Song object:

```
public class PopulateSongs {
    private static List<Song> songList;
    private static Song song;

    public static List<Song> populateFromFile() {
        List<String> songs = DirWalker.readSerializedSongPathsFile();
        List<Song> listOfSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String item : songs) {
            song = new Song();
            File file = new File(item);
            System.out.println(item);
            try {
                AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
                if (fileFormat instanceof TAudioFileFormat) {
                    Map<?, ?> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) fileFormat).properties();
                    song.setPath(item);
                    song.setArtistName((String) properties.get("author"));
                    song.setAlbumName((String) properties.get("album"));
                    song.setSongName((String) properties.get("title"));
                    song.setReleaseDate((String) properties.get("date"));
                    song.setGenre((String) properties.get("mp3.id3tag.genre"));
                    song.setTrackNumber((String) properties.get("mp3.id3tag.track"));
                    song.setLength((Long) properties.get("duration"));
                    song.setComposer((String) properties.get("mp3.id3tag.composer"));
                    song.setPublisher((String) properties.get("mp3.id3tag.publisher"));
                    song.setAlbumID(1);
                    song.setArtistID(1);
                    songList.add(song);
                } else {
                    throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return listOfSongs;
    }
.....continues>>>
```

When it gets to the following to be saved the list has a value of null but a size of over 49K.

```
public void saveSerializedSongInfoFile (List<Song> sl) {
//        List<Song> sortedSongList = SortSongList.sortSongBy(sl, SongComparator.Order.ARTIST);
        System.out.println("Size of Song List To Be Written: " + s1.size() + "\n");
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream =
                     new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(savePath))) {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(sl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now here is were I am baffled, this is the output for the SongList when running debug in IntelliJ.  The list has a size, the objects have accurate values but the whole object is null.

This is the debug values (I have expanded a couple to show the values:

```
songs = {ArrayList@511}  size = 49783
listOfSongs = {ArrayList@512}  size = 49782
 0 = {Song@515} "null"
  path = "m:\tunes\10,000 Maniacs\In My Tribe\01 - What's The Matter Here_.mp3"
  songName = "What's The Matter Here?"
  artistName = "10,000 Maniacs"
  albumName = "In My Tribe"
  releaseDate = "1987"
  trackNumber = "1"
  composer = "Natalie Merchant/Robert Buck"
  genre = "Soft Rock"
  length = "4:51"
  publisher = "Elektra"
  artistID = 1
  albumID = 1
 1 = {Song@669} "null"
 2 = {Song@670} "null"
 3 = {Song@671} "null"
 4 = {Song@672} "null"
 5 = {Song@673} "null"
 6 = {Song@674} "null"
 7 = {Song@675} "null"
 8 = {Song@676} "null"
 9 = {Song@677} "null"
 10 = {Song@678} "null"
 11 = {Song@679} "null"
 12 = {Song@680} "null"
 13 = {Song@681} "null"
 14 = {Song@682} "null"
 15 = {Song@683} "null"
 16 = {Song@684} "null"
 17 = {Song@685} "null"
 18 = {Song@686} "null"
 19 = {Song@687} "null"
 20 = {Song@688} "null"
 21 = {Song@689} "null"
 22 = {Song@690} "null"
 23 = {Song@691} "null"
 24 = {Song@692} "null"
 25 = {Song@693} "null"
 26 = {Song@694} "null"
  path = "m:\tunes\AC-DC\1 Studio albums\1974 High Voltage (Australian Editions) @320\02 - She's Got Balls.mp3"
  songName = "She's Got Balls"
  artistName = "AC/DC"
  albumName = "High Voltage"
  releaseDate = "1975"
  trackNumber = "2"
  composer = null
  genre = "Hard Rock"
  length = "4:48"
  publisher = "Albert Productions"
  artistID = 1
  albumID = 1
 27 = {Song@695} "null"
 28 = {Song@696} "null"
 29 = {Song@697} "null"
 30 = {Song@698} "null"
 31 = {Song@699} "null"

 .......and this continues for the rest of the array.
```

Anyone who understands this, can you explain it to me...preferably with fix :).

Comment: `Song#toString` is returning `null`?

Comment: To expand on @MadProgrammer comment, the values aren't null, you're just printing (why?) the built string then returning null. The fact that the array values are all showing `Song@669` with different numbers mean that you do have different objects assigned in the array.

Comment: Show implementation of `Song.toString`

Comment: @Dima It's already there ...

Comment: I see. Well, it returns `null`. What do you expect to be printed out???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These items aren't `null`. You're debugger is showing you this:

```
1 = {Song@669} "null"
index = {ClassName@ObjectId} "Result of 'toString()'"
```

And since your `Song#toString` looks like this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Values for this song:");
    sb.append("\n\tArtist: " + artistName);
    sb.append("\n\tTitle: " + songName);
    sb.append("\n\tRelease Date: " + releaseDate);
    sb.append("\n\tTrack Number: " + trackNumber);
    sb.append("\n\tComposer: " + composer);
    sb.append("\n\tPublisher: " + publisher);
    sb.append("\n\tLength: " + length);
    sb.append("\n");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return null;
}
```

it is quite clear why it shows *"null"*. `toString` is supposed to return a String representation of an object. Your implementation just prints this representation and returns `null` then. You need to return `sb.toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    //...
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had been using the Override toString() doing some testing earlier.  I for got that it would muck things up.